# Running some commands in script as user

Tags: bash, sudo

I am trying to change a config file on a client, remotely from a server. This is an experimental testbed. I have setup so that the server's `rsa_pub` key is in the client's authorized keys file.

When I run a script (this needs to run as root), I am prompted for the client machine's password when I attempt to change the file. If I run it as user, then I am not. I also tried using the `sudo -u` switch which does not seem to work as well.

Run as user (This works):

```
echo 'prio 0' | ssh user@192.168.10.10 "cat > /home/user/priofile.txt"
```

Still running as user, but with `-u` switch (This works):

```
$ sudo -u user echo 'prio 0' | ssh user@192.168.10.10 "cat > /home/user/priofile.txt"
```

Run as root:

```
# sudo -u user echo 'prio 0' | ssh user@192.168.10.10 "cat > /home/user/priofile.txt"
user@192.168.10.10's password:
```

Why would it prompt me for password although I am trying to run it as user?

Comment: Is it possible that the authorised key in the client's file matching the `user` user and not `root` user?

Comment: Yes! exactly the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @jamie You missunderstood the concepts of stackoverflow. Your question is not related to programming. Also it is something that has been dicussed many times on many, many places before. Please delete this question and read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before you post your next question on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

The root user's keys are stored under `/root/.ssh/`. These keys need to be copied to the remote client to facilitate password-free access.